# PHP text truncate limit characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have $Description field is a long text from MySql database. Following displays the full text but I really want to display only 50 characters instead of full text length.

```
 <?php  echo $row['Description'];?>
```

I have tried several different options but I don't get any results.

I hope someone can guide me through this. 
Thank you for your time and help.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a substr

```
<?php  echo substr($row['Description'], 0, 50);   ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **substr** function:

```
<?php  echo substr($row['Description'], 0, 50);?>
```